# Disable author select in news-webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, sharepoint-news

[image]

SharePoint news allows users to select **authors other then themselves** for news-messages. Is it possible to disable this option so users can only post news on behalf of themself?

Microsoft's documentation doesn't contain a lot of information about news so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no OOTB way to limit current users from selecting other user's name in author of Site Page/News.